# cast long into pointer

Tags: c

Can this cast fail and when?

```
long x=-1;
long y = (long)(void*)x;
assert(x==y);
```

More specifically, how to detect if the above cast is OK at compile time.

Comment: Just guessing: is that for `pthread_create`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more portable way (on the C99 standard variant) is to `#include <stdint.h>` and then cast pointers to `intptr_t` (and back). This integer type is guaranteed to be the size of a pointer.

Comment: Note that the OP is casting integer->pointer->integer, which in my understanding of the standard is slightly less defined than pointer->integer->pointer.

Comment: I forgot the details, and I think the standards changed on this aspect. In practice function pointers are pointers, in theory not exactly.

Comment: @Basile: the difference here is not theory vs practice - rather, the C standard has to cope with existing architectures where code and data pointers have representations of different sizes (eg far vs near); even today, there are micro-controllers without flat memory model, and you don't even have to look for exotic architectures - any x86 cpu can still be used in real-mode

Comment: I think that POSIX committee considered at some time to have `dlsym` and another function (perhaps `dlfsym`?) to deal with function pointers which are not the same size as data pointers, but they gave up the idea, so at least in the POSIX realm, practically speaking, function pointers are the same size as data pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Portably no. 
I know even an implementation where this will fail. x86 real mode with memory models tiny, small and medium. A `long` is 32 bit and pointers are 16 bits.
Other microcontrollers with Harvard architecture will probably fail too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember this won't fail, given that you correct the type of y to `(long)(void*)`.

Comment: Hm?  "(long)(void*)" is not a type.  It is a series of two casts, first casting to `void*` and then casting to `long`.

Answer (score 0):

This may fail on architectures where a long int and a pointer is not the same size. Some 64bit architectures has this behaviour. Like Basile says, use intptr_t instead if available on your system.

You can detect this situation at compile time like this:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(COND,MSG) typedef char static_assertion_##MSG[(COND)?1:-1]
STATIC_ASSERT((sizeof(void*) > sizeof(long)), incompatible_pointer_size);
```

Comment: No,`sizeof` cannot appear in preprocessor expressions, so the above is unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: True about the preprocessor, but the idea that `sizeof (void*) > sizeof (long)` can be true is the important message here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch is right, you have to use the static assert-trick. I'll edit the response.

Comment: Is this the already edited one?